# Do different fish effects stack?

Tags: torchlight

I have fished quite a lot of fish and I have got a bunch of prismatic morey, frenzy fish and trufflesnout fish. I tried looking everywhere online but i cannot find any information as to what happens if I eat all three different fish at once.  Will the effects stack or not?

It's especially important for me since I'm playing the game at the hardest difficulty.

Comment: Thanks for editing my post Christi, Grammar is not my strong suit. But the fish really are morey fish, haha

Comment: I can tell you for a fact that transformation fish do not stack.  When you feed your pet a new fish, he will turn into whatever the most recent fish dictates.  As for buffing fish (like increasing defense or health for a period of time), your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: @GnomeSlice yea I figured with the transformation fish it wouldn't stack although be pretty awesome and hilarious if it would. haha

Comment: @Xitcod13 You can always edit it again if anything needs to be fixed...just hit the "edit" button at the bottom left of your question if you see something that could be better. I know I often end up editing my answers five or ten times before I'm happy with them. Questions usually need less editing in my experience (it's important to not change what your're asking, while an answer can change a bit more freely), but never be shy about making a good edit.

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock Man you have no idea how many times i edit my questions. Im dyslexic, I want my questions to be perfectly clear but Im always disappointed in the clarity. Thank goodness other people can edit my posts. Im really thankful for that.

Comment: Fair enough.  I blame Torchlight for that one, since Moray Eels are a Real Thing.

Comment: I think the effect fish do stack, and I'm pretty sure they are for your pet, not you.

Comment: How about you try to feed the fish to your pet and see what happens?

Comment: I can test this later, if I remember.  Tonight probably.  If I remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can know the fish that direcly affects your character end up in the items tab while the items in the fish tab only affect your pet. I did a bit of testing today on the prismatic morey, frenzy fish and trufflesnout fish. Each fish affects separate abilities so they should stack up nicely unless they overwrite each other. The pet tab only displays basic information about the pet which makes testing the troufflesnout difficult. I did however test feeding different shape-changing fish to the pet and each one overwrote the previous one. The numerical statistics tied to that shape also switched to that of the new shape. I confirmed this by having two types of shape-changing fish in stacks and alternating between them to observe the change in statistics.

Then I assumed that if the buffing fish effects would overwrite each other considering that they affect different stats, troufflesnout and morey should remove the speed increase from the frenzy fish. So I fed my pet the frenzy fish which caused a noticeable increase in speed and then I fed it the trufflesnout and prismatic morey to it to see if the speed boost would be lost. As far as I could see the pet retained the speed boost and attack speed for the full duration during this experiment and even when I fed it a shape-changing fish. So I conclude that yes, the effects do stack with each other.